# Rewrite without url changing

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect (without url changing) from **mysite.com/order/business** to **mysite.com/order/index.php?tariff=business**

I have this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase     /
RewriteRule order/(startup|business|vip) order/index.php?tariff=$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works correctly on my localhost, but on shared hosting I have redirect (url is changing). What's wrong? How I can to fix it?

Comment: Seems like a good question but got no answer in 4 years. Is StackExchange working right?